# upload an "image" or "picture", which is the right text to convey?

Tags: website-design, usability

Working on the feedback form with an image or picture attachment, let me know which is the right text be used?

Comment: For use on the web, it is an image. A picture is what you hang on your wall.

Comment: What is it a picture / image of? What is the context of this question?

Answer (score 3):

image: mostly related to digital photo. More technical term

picture: can be digital photos , paintings. Less technical term

If you are expecting people to upload their photo,paintings most appropriate will be Picture
If you are expecting people to upload photo of  things ,most appropriate will be Image.

its also depends on context:

Technical Issues , customer feedback etc: use Image
Less Technical like Profile Pics etc: Use Picture

Answer (score 1):

The bigger question is who is your audience.

In word, Excel, etc; they use the word "Insert Picture". In Adobe Photoshop, where users mostly know the different types of images, uses "Insert Image". So, the answer to your question lies in the audience.